# Android: performance increase of the app after 15s-120s. Why?

Tags: android

I have a bit of a problem with a game I am working on. The game runs very well on most devices, except Samsung Tab and Galaxy S (it could be more, but I have reports about those two).

What happens on those devices is that the app appear extremely sluggish for 15s-120s then speeds up dramatically (from 5fs to 30fps, which is the normal performance elsewhere). This seems to happen only when the game is installed (or reinstalled).

What could cause that problem?

- On the first run, we create a couple of files on the SD card to store settings, but I doubt that could have a lasting effect?
- The JIT takes a whiles to kick in? But it runs perfectly fine on other platform with and without the JIT. Admitedly, by disabling the JIT, it appears that the slowdown will last longer on the Tab, so there may be an effect.
- Could it be that the device tries to rearrange out the objects are laid out in memory? The game does take quite a bit of space in memory.
- Is there any known problem with Samsung devices? (It appears to be a problem on those only)

Any help is welcome.

Comment: Take a look at http://developer.android.com/guide/developing/tools/traceview.html to profile your app.

Comment: yes, I wish I had access to one here, but I'll get it in a week

Comment: Have you tested these devices using a different SD card?  I assume you are using OpenGL for this game, maybe some methods you are using take a while to be optimized on those devices gfx chip? Another note: I do believe that most of the Galaxy S devices besides the Tab are stuck on 2.1, which doesn't include JIT, so your issue may not be that.

Comment: If disabling JIT makes it last longer but the problem eventually goes away then it is not the JIT.  One difference with Samsung devices is that they use their own filesystem (http://movitool.ntd.homelinux.org/trac/movitool/wiki/RFS).  But if you are creating files on the sdcard this may not be a factor.  Profiling the I/O on the device would be interesting to see if it coincides with the performance hit, shell in and run *iostat -c* and look at %iowait for starters.

Answer (score 3):

You could try to call `dalvik.system.VMRuntime.getRuntime().setMinimumHeapSize()` early in your app with about the size of the heap while your game runs. This will allocate the target heap size at once and avoid reallocs.

I know it is deprecated but who cares if it helps.

Comment: dalvik.system.VMRuntime cannot be resolved to a type, How to solve this ?

Comment: It has been removed from the SDK but you can still call it using reflection:

    Class<?> rt = Class.forName("dalvik.system.VMRuntime");
   Object runtime = rt.getMethod("getRuntime").invoke(null);
   rt.getMethod("setMinimumHeapSize", Long.TYPE).invoke(runtime, 16 * 1024 * 1024);

I just ran a brief test and it doesn't seem to do anything on newer devices, though.